# What could be causing the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter ClassNotFoundException with Struts2 when using the latest Struts 2.5.29 version?

Tags: java, exception, struts2, classnotfoundexception

I'm building my first application with Struts2 and I'm running into a *ClassNotFoundException* when I run the application.

Just for some background. I used this link to download the latest Struts2 version 2.5.29 (tried using both the Full Distribution and Essential Dependencies only versions but getting the same ClassNotFoundException for both versions): https://struts.apache.org/download.cgi

After downloading the Struts2 library, I added the jar files into my project, following this Struts 2 setting up tutorial from Java Brains(which asks you to add the jar files to both the project classpath and the WEB-INF lib folder): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LhjEgxJ080g&list=PLB7BB551126EDD5E0&index=3

Here are my Java files:

**struts.xml**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.5//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.5.dtd">
        
<struts>

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="com.struts.action.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    
    </package>



</struts>
```

**web.xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  
  <display-name>Struts2Starter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  
  <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    
</web-app>
```

**TutorialAction:**

```java
package com.struts.action;

public class TutorialAction {
    
    public String execute() {
        
        System.out.println("Hello from execute");
        return "success";
    }

}
```

**And here is the error that I'm getting:**

```
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [656] milliseconds
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.58]
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:37 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:38 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter [struts2]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:534)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5256)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:345)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:476)

Mar 09, 2022 10:01:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:40 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Struts2Starter] startup failed due to previous errors
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:40 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Mar 09, 2022 10:01:40 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in [8729] milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved, kind of. The *ClassNotFoundException* error was due to the jar files not properly being added to the Web Deployment Assembly. Now that I readded them, that exception is no longer popping up on the console.

A different issue is coming up and that is: There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name [getTutorial] associated with context path [/Struts2Starter].

I'll have to review my url-action mappings in the struts.xml file. And I will post that as a new question if need be.